# How to send an Email with the tasks completed on Azure DevOps pipeline upon deploy?

Tags: azure, email, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'd like to send an email when we deploy on staging, and the email should contain the tasks, or the Pull Requests (title) that will be added to the environment. Is there a way to do this? I thought about comparing the Pull Requests' creation data, with the latest deploy's date, but I don't know if is this possible. I'm not too experienced with Azure DevOps pipelines, and I'm curious if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Azure DevOps sends an email notification to team members after the compilation succeeds or fails.

To create it for CI/CD pipeline [check here](https://edi.wang/post/2019/2/21/send-email-after-release-deployment-in-azure-devops) the complete steps to configure email setting.

For more information please refer this SO THREAD: [Best way to send email notification in an Azure DevOps build pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54014145/best-way-to-send-email-notification-in-an-azure-devops-build-pipeline-do-not-wa)