# Customize Azure DevOps Approval Email

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a release pipeline in Azure DevOps that requires approval from a Senior Developer. I want to be able to customize the email notification that goes out requiring them to approve the release.

Is there some way I can do this? To be able to use Python to achieve this would be ideal.

Comment: Have you tried enabling the notifications using portal??

Answer (score 0):

- *As per the local environment you have direct options to enable notifications in your project settings. Below is the image to achieve that.*

[image]

Comment: I understand that notifications can be approved through here, but what I want to do is customize the actual email notification that goes out. For example, I want to add an URL to the email. This does not address that.

Answer (score 0):

> what I want to do is customize the actual email notification that goes out. For example, I want to add an URL to the email. This does not address that.

If you're customizing the content of your message, I am afraid there is no such way to achieve this at this moment.

We could only set the notifications for the Approve.

As a workaround, we could add a stage at first of the release pipeline, and add the powershell task to sent the e-mail:

[Send simple email in Azure DevOps using PowerShell (without any smtp server)](https://medium.com/globant/send-simple-email-in-azure-devops-using-powershell-without-any-smtp-server-bd669a24e544)

or we could use the [send mail](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask) task, you could check another thread for some more details:

[Best way to send email notification in an Azure DevOps build pipeline? Do not want to use "Notifications Module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54014145/best-way-to-send-email-notification-in-an-azure-devops-build-pipeline-do-not-wa)

Comment: This would result in two emails though, right? The email with the message I want to include and then the approval email from DevOps. This actually my existing solution. What I want to do is get rid of one email.

Comment: @MinuraPunchihewa, You could disable the approval email from DevOps by disable the subscription for approval in the project setting.

Comment: I could have other release pipelines that require approvals as well. Is it possible to disable approval notifications for a particular release pipeline for all users?

Comment: @MinuraPunchihewa, Yes, you could just disable the default subscription "Deployment approval pending".

Comment: But, this will disable approvals for all pipelines in the subscription, right? I don't want that. This will need to apply only to this particular pipeline.